# check duplicates between two columns

Tags: excel, duplicates

I have a sheet where Column A is a set of unique ID's and Column B is a Boolean value of Open or Closed. Every week I download a csv file containing the same, but updated list of unique ID's and Boolean values and merge it with the previous weeks list. Some of the values in Column B will stay the same and some will change. I need to identify the rows where the value in Column A is the same and the value in Column B is not.

Example

```
 |  A  |  B
1| 111 | Open
2| 111 | Open
3| 112 | Open
4| 112 | Closed
5| 113 | Closed
6| 113 | Closed
```

In the above example, I would like to identify rows 3 and 4 because their values in Column A are duplicates, but their values in Column B are different.

Comment: This is quite simple in VBA - what have you tried? What isn't working? Can you post your code?

Comment: I'm very new to using excel in any fashion other than just recording data. I've tried messing with some IF and Vlookup functions, but haven't found the right combination. I believe the answer is something similar to: =IF(VLOOKUP(A2,A:A,1)=VLOOKUP(A2,A:A,1) & (VLOOKUP(B2,A:A,1)=VLOOKUP(B2,A:A,1),"true","false")